# How to adjust parenthesis size and set font and size of the label partially in matplotlib labels?

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, label

I know the title does not make any sense. But, I tried to explain what I need here. I have a plot with the following labels.

```
plt.xlabel(r'$\tau^P_j$ (day)', fontsize=12)
plt.ylabel(r'$\rho(\{j\},k^*)$', fontsize=12)
```

For x label, I want to change the font of the text part to times new roman and font size to something smaller. The function `fontsize=12` applies to both the equation and the text parts in the label and the text part seems bigger than the math part, though they are both 12.

In addition, I need to adjust the size of the parenthesis in y label. The curly brackets appear much larger than the parenthesis. I tried `(r'$\rho\big(\{j\},k^*\big)$', fontsize=12)`, but no luck. I am using Python 2.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things work fine for me in `python 3.6.5` and `matplotlib 2.2.2`. I present below an answer to demonstrate the difference, both as axes labels and as texts (just to present y-label horizontally to notice the difference.

**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rc
rc('text', usetex=True)
plt.rcParams['text.latex.preamble']=[r"\usepackage{amsmath}"]
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 4))

x = range(6)
plt.plot(x, x)
plt.xlabel(r'$\tau^P_j$ $\text{\small{(day)}}$', fontsize=12)
plt.ylabel(r'$\rho\big(\{j\},k^*\big)$', fontsize=12)

plt.text(1,4, r'$\rho(\{j\},k^*)$', fontsize=12)
plt.text(1,3, r'$\rho\big(\{j\},k^*\big)$', fontsize=12)

plt.text(3,2, r'$\tau^P_j$ $\text{\small{(day)}}$', fontsize=12)
plt.text(3,1, r'$\tau^P_j$ (day)', fontsize=12)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Because this answer is meant to show that some code works as is, it would be beneficial if it was a true [mcve], i.e. a runnable code with all non-default rcParams (if there are any) mentionned. Possibly the difference to OP's case is the use of `usetex`? Or a custom font setting?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: Thanks for pointing it out. I edited my answer.